# Are all AAA ratings (from various credit rating agencies) equivalent?

Tags: bonds, bond-funds, credit-rating-agency

I am peeking into holdings of various ultra-short term debt mutual funds (average maturity of bonds should be less than 1 year) and am coming up with `AAA` ratings of at least three different agencies:
1. Brickworks
2. CRISIL
3. CARE
4. ICRA

Is it correct to assume that AAA ratings from all these agencies are equally `AAA`?

Comment: They are "equivalent" in the sense that none of them are reliable.

Comment: @SimonB: Yes. You are right. The whole ratings thing seems like a giant scam...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it correct to assume that AAA ratings from all these agencies are equally AAA?

Every agency has slightly different evaluation criteria of what an AAA is. Generally this rating means the company/fund are doing well and are in top category. There are cases where the same company is evaluated and given slightly different ratings, so they are not exactly same, but are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. This means that when a mutual fund claims its portfolio is 80% AAA rated bonds, I do not need to see what agency rated them. Right?

Comment: @Sriram In general Yes.